# libgdx android shader effect glow

Tags: java, android, libgdx, 2d-games

sorry for my English but I'm not very good.
The question is how to get a flash or glow effect on a label or image using libgdx in android. I read somewhere that shaders or also with glow effect on the image which I have done but I'm not convinced the outcome. I hope you can help me. regards

Comment: http://loading.com.mx/wp-content/uploads/2013/10/candy-crush-saga-dulces-rayados.jpg

Comment: Make textures already with glow effect.

Comment: Have you found the solution ?